# Move files back by 2 directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, mv

```
$ cat file
/tmp/foldera/folderb/folderc/file1
/tmp/folderc/folderd/foldere/file2
/tmp/folderf/folderg/folderh/file3
```

Need to move this files to

```
/tmp/foldera/
/tmp/folderc/
/tmp/folderf/
```

respectively using a loop or any easy handy way to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
  mv -v -- "$l" "${l%/*/*/*}/"
done <file
```

- `while IFS= read -r l` will read the `file` line by line.
- `mv -v` move the files and `-v` tells `mv` to be verbose

  - `"$l"` is the source filename
  - `"${l%/*/*/*}/"` is the target directory. It removes 3 slashes and what is between them (`/*/*/*`) from the back end of the filename.

---

This will produce:

```
»/tmp/foldera/folderb/folderc/file1“ -> »/tmp/foldera/file1“
»/tmp/folderc/folderd/foldere/file2“ -> »/tmp/folderc/file2“
»/tmp/folderf/folderg/folderh/file3“ -> »/tmp/folderf/file3“
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll suggest a similar answer as chaos, but using `dirname`

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
    mv -- "$l" "$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$l")")"
done <file
```

`dirname` reports the path of the directory a file/directory is located in. This has the advantage of being able to handle moving a directory as well, in case your file has an entry like:

```
/tmp/foldera/folderb/folderc/folderd/
```